# How do I exclude sports-related results from Google Search?

Tags: google-search

There is nothing I hate more than searching the name of a city I’m visiting on Google and having all the relevant results that come up be related to football. Is there a way to tell Google that I’m not interested in sports and that no, I’m not interested in “SomeCity F.C.” fixtures when I search for “SomeCity”?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
barcelona
```

[image: 0]

---

search for:

```
barcelona -football -sport -tenis
```

[image: 0]